# How can I enable smooth scrolling in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-reader

I just updated to the latest **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC**, and since then, the scrolling in the pdf documents is very poor, it is like **lines are jumping on the screen**.

This problem wasn't in the previous version of Adobe Reader XI. And even now other applications like chrome is having smooth scrolling normally (It is not a problem in my driver).

I did many searches, but I found no results at all!
I am running Windows 7 Ultimate - 32 bits.

Comment: Do you only encounter this problem on your own computer, or also on other ones?

Comment: Yes, I have this problem on my own laptop.